# Problem about internal resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

> *Problem from BdPHO 2016:*
>
> A resistance of 4 Ohm is connected across a cell. Then it is replaced by another resistance of 1 Ohm. It is found that power dissipated in the resistance in both cases is same. What is the internal resistance of the cell?

This doesn’t make sense to me. I think it is saying that
$$\frac{E}{4\,\mathrm{Ohm}+r} = \frac{E}{1\,\mathrm{Ohm}+r}$$
But this will mean that $4 = 1$. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Whenever you post a problem that is you are generally supposed to solve on your own, remember to tag it with (homework-and-excercises) and consult the [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/55657). To make a centered (“displayed”) equation, enclose it in double dollar signs. Also,  SI capitalizes for units derived from people’s names, even though the units are not usually capitalized in running text. *E.g.* resistance is measured in ohms, while one of the loads you mention in your question has resistance $4\,\mathrm{Ohm}$. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power dissipated in the external resistor is the product of current and voltage. The equation you need to solve is going to be a quadratic. If we assume the voltage of the unloaded cell is $V_0$, we can write

$$I_1 = \frac{V_0}{R_1+R_i}\\
P_1 = I_2^2R_1$$

And the same for $I_2$, with appropriate changes. If $P_1=P_2$, it follows that

$$\left(\frac{V_0}{R_1+R_i}\right)^2 R_1 = \left(\frac{V_0}{R_2+R_i}\right)^2 R_2$$

You will find that this has a valid solution, $R_i=\sqrt{R_1 R_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the internal resistance use
$$ R_{int}=\bigg(\frac{V_o}{V_L}-1\bigg)R_L$$
you have enough info to get rid of unknowns $V_o$ and $V_L$, having two instances of this equation.

Comment: Unless the cell is ideal or voltage controlled, there can be a voltage change when different loads are used.